# Selecting an HTML element by it's ID attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I picked up some code on CodePen to help me dynamically replace the content of divs. It works, but as often happens when borrowing someone's code, I can't actually mold it to what I want it to do.

The original code provides pictures of animals, and when you click it, it sends the text of the name of the animal to a div. The Javascript looks like this:

```
$('#kittens').click(function() {
  $('div').html('Kittens');
});


$('#aardvark').click(function() {
  $('div').html('Aardvark');
});
```

I'm applying it to a more complicated webpage, so I really can't have it just replace the first level div with the word "Kittens."

I've found that by keeping the single quotes, I can put any text or code I want in there and it works just fine, but only if I'm writing to the first level div.

So I figure to target it, I should just give it the div ID. Something like:

```
$('#kittens').click(function() {
  $('myDivName').html('Kittens');
});
```

This does nothing. I've also tried 'id=myDivName' , 'id="myDivName"' , id: myDivName , and a few others I can't recall right now. Nothing I can come up with seems to work.

Does anybody know how this parameter works and how I can get it to target just the div I want?

Comment: It's either `'#myDivName'` or `'[id="myDivName"]'`, the latter being the unrecommended way of doing it.

Comment: Please read basic concepts of CSS selectors, Its worth it before you try out jQuery

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors work just like CSS selectors, so instead of `$('myDivName')`, do `$('#myDivName')`

Answer (score 0):

when referencing an element in jquery, you need to use it's css selector. For an element with an id `"myDivName"` that selector would be `#myDivName` so your jquery would look like:

```
$('#kittens').click(function() {
    $('#myDivName').html('Kittens');
});
```